# Fazer com que um combobox assuma valores C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Tenho duvidas de fazer com que a combobox assuma um valor.

Tenho duas combobox com os itens 'baixo, medio e alto' e quero que se seleciono baixa no combobox ela assuma o valor 0, se seleciono medio ela assuma 0,5 e se seleciono alto ela assuma 1. E salvar eles valores no BD.

Answer (score 3):

Isto é bem simples, basta seguir o exemplo abaixo:

```
//Os objetos para serem utilizados
var objetos = new List<object>();

objetos.Add(new {valor = 0, nome = "Baixo"});
objetos.Add(new {valor = 0.5, nome = "Médio"});
objetos.Add(new {valor = 1, nome = "Alto"});

//É o nome da propriedade do objeto que será visível para o usuário
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "valor";
//É o nome da propriedade do objeto que servirá de valor
comboBox1.ValueMember = "nome";
comboBox1.DataSource = objetos;
```

E para pegar o valor que foi selecionado pelo usuário basta fazer isto:

```
//Exemplo de como pegar o valor que foi selecionado pelo usuário
var valorSelecionado = (double)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Valeu Richard, ajudou muito. surgiu mais uma dúvida.
Quando pego o item Selecionado ele traz td a linha ({valor = 1, nome = "Alto"}).
É possível pegar só o que contem no displaymenber?

Comment: @DiegoPaganini O display member é o valor Exibido, se você quiser pegar o texto que usuário selecionou é só usar comboBox1.Text ou comboBox1.SelectedTex. O comboBox1.SelectedItem vai retornar o objeto inteiro, agora se você quiser somente o valor é só usar o comboBox1.SelectedValue.

Answer (score 1):

Passe objetos neste caso ao ComboBox:

```
// crie uma classe que represente sua medida
public class Medida
{
    public string Representacao { get; set; }

    public double Valor { get; set; }

    // IMPORTANTE: isto é usado pelo ComboBox
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Representacao;
    }
}
```

Exemplo na adição de itens:

```
Medida[] medidas = new Medida[]
    {
        new Medida() {Representacao = "Alto", Valor = 0.75 },
        new Medida() {Representacao = "Médio", Valor = 0.50 },
        new Medida() {Representacao = "Baixo", Valor = 0.25 },
    };
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(medidas);
```

Como pegar o valor que você quer para atualizar o banco de dados:

```
// após o usuário selecionar o item do ComboBox você pode pegar o valor a partir disso:
// TODO: validar se o item é nulo ou não
double valor = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as Medida).Valor;
```